# Flutter How to validate DateTime isn't null

Tags: flutter

I'd like to validate the date entered by the user, so the date shouldn't be null
how to add the validation ?!!
Here my code I want the date different of null otherwise display a message to the user

```
TextFormField(
              readOnly: true,
              controller: dateController,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.length != null) {
                  return 'no';
                }
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Pick your Date'),
              onTap: () async {
                var date = await showDatePicker(
                    context: context,
                    initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                    firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                    lastDate: DateTime(2100));
                dateController.text = date.toString().substring(0, 10);
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
validator: (value) {
   if (value.isEmpty) 
     return "Please pick a date";
 }
```

This is assuming that you did not give an initial value to your dateController.

If you did give it an initial value, for example,

```
dateController.text = "Please pick a date"

if (dateController.text == "Please pick a date") 
         return "Please pick a date";
```

This will check if the value of the controller has changed from the initial value or not. If it didn't change, it'll show the text being returned in the if statement. When your user picks a date, you are change the value of it to the date picked, so it'll pass the validation, otherwise, it'll fail.

Comment: Where should i use the second statement  dateController.text = "Please pick a date"

if (dateController.text == "Please pick a date") 
         return "Please pick a date";

Comment: Outside your build method, for example after creating it, or in initstate write `dateController.text = "Please pick a date"`

The if statment inside your validator, replace `if (value.isEmpty)` with `if (dateController.text == "Please pick a date")`

Answer (score 0):

```
date ?? DateTime.now();
```

`date` is Your Date. ?? will check its null or not then if its null it will pick `DateTime.now();`